# Cuando intento correr ionic cordova run android obtengo el error de "No installed build tools found"

Tags: android, cordova, ionic4

Este es la salida que obtengo
What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
/home/anyamigcr/Documentos/testingpush/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/home/anyamigcr/Documentos/testingpush/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 68
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: intentaste `ionic cordova platform add android` `ionic corodva build android` y luego `ionic cordova run android`